# Elasticsearch: How do I boost a result from a query if it also exists in a different index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking to make a suggestions query on an index `geolocations` and have it boosted if a separate index `media` contains a returned doc from geolocations. And only return `geolocations`

Example *doc* from `geolocations`

```
{
    "_index": "geolocations",
    "_id": "986",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "city": {
            "id": 977,
            "postalCode": "3854",
            "name": "New Castle",
            "latitude": 43.06558,
            "longitude": -70.72003,
            "countyName": "Rockingham",
            "countyNamesAll": "Rockingham",
            "timezone": "America/New_York"
        },
        "state": {
            "id": 34,
            "code": "NH",
            "name": "New Hampshire"
        },
        "country": {
            "id": 2,
            "code": "US"
        }
    }
}
```

Example *doc* from `media`

```
{
    "_index": "local-media-v1",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
        "geolocation": {
            "city_id": 977,
            "postal_code": 3854,
            "state_code": "NH",
            "city_name": "New Castle",
            "county_name": "Rockingham",
            "timezone": "America/New_York",
            "state_name": "New Hampshire",
            "country_code": "US",
            "coordinates": [
              43.06558,
              -70.72003
            ]
        },
        [..removed trivial fields..]
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a field: `city.id` in `geolocations`, and `geolocation.city_id` in `media` - similarly, there are other matching fields, like `city.name`//`geolocation.city_name`

What I want is a query on `geolocations`, lets say something like:

```
// geolocations
{
  "suggest" : {
    "suggestions" : {
      "text" : "New Cas",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "city.name",
        "sort": "score",
        "prefix_length": 2,
        "min_word_length": 3,
        "max_edits": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
// Return example
"suggest": {
    "suggestions": [
      {
        "text": "New Cast",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 8,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "New Castle",
            "score": 0.75,
            "freq": 8
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

That gets boosted by some amount if *any* `media` contains the found suggested city.

Note: I dont want to exclude geolocations just because there isnt a matching `media`, I still want them in the results, just at the bottom, with the ones that match `media` at the top. (Preferably by the number of times its matches media)

I havent been able to try too much, but I feel like I am getting closer by using comma separated indices in the url. But again, not sure where to even start with this.

I dont need to use `suggest` - I am up for any possible way!

Hopefully this makes sense! Also, I think this is actually my first Stack Overflow question, so I hope I provided what I needed

**UPDATE**
I think I have gotten closer with this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "New*",
      "fields": [
        "geolocation.city.name",
        "city.name"
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "media": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "_index": "local-media-v1"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "cities": {
          "terms": {
            "script": "if (doc.containsKey('geolocation.city.name')) { doc[\"geolocation.city.name\"].value + \", \" + doc[\"geolocation.state.name\"].value + \"|\" + doc[\"geolocation.city.id\"].value }"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "geolocation": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "_index": "local-geolocations-v1"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "cities": {
          "terms": {
            "script": "if (doc.containsKey('city.name')) { doc[\"city.name\"].value + \", \" + doc[\"state.name\"].value + \"|\" + doc[\"city.id\"].value }"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 514,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "media": {
      "doc_count": 2,
      "cities": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "New Castle, New Hampshire|977",
            "doc_count": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "geolocation": {
      "doc_count": 512,
      "cities": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 1,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 502,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "New Albany, Indiana|15713",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "New Albany, Ohio|14062",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "New Albany, Pennsylvania|5952",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "New Albin, Iowa|17772",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "New Alexandria, Pennsylvania|4758",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "New Athens, Illinois|21798",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "New Athens, Ohio|14437",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "New Auburn, Minnesota|18968",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "New Auburn, Wisconsin|18675",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "New Baden, Illinois|21799",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And now I have been trying hard to combine the two results into one list :/

I could do this on the API but it would be a lot DRYer if I can just tie it up in Elastic Search